# pandas dataframe makes a boolean column based on the date in the list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, boolean

Assuming there is a data frame with 2 columns ds, y (the input of fbprophet https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html)

```
        ds        y
2021-03-17  3135.73
2021-03-18  3027.99
2021-03-19  3074.96
2021-03-22  3110.87
2021-03-23  3110.87
2021-03-24  3110.87
2021-03-25  3110.87
```

Here is the code to generate this dataframe

```
data = \
    {
    'ds':['2021-03-17','2021-03-18','2021-03-19','2021-03-22','2021-03-23','2021-03-24','2021-03-25'],
    'y':['3135.73','3027.99','3074.96','3110.87','3110.87','3110.87','3110.87']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How could I generate 2 new boolean columns on_season, off_season

based on the "date" in a loop?

So for example, if the ds column is in between date and date-2, then on_season=TRUE, off_season = OFF

desired output since the date in the loop here are '2021-03-19','2021-03-25'. So on_season is between '2021-03-19' and '2021-03-17' and '2021-03-25' and '2021-03-23'.

```
        ds        y    on_season    off_season     
2021-03-17  3135.73         TRUE         FALSE  
2021-03-18  3027.99         TRUE         FALSE
2021-03-19  3074.96         TRUE         FALSE  
2021-03-22  3110.87        FALSE          TRUE
2021-03-23  3110.87         TRUE         FALSE
2021-03-24  3110.87         TRUE         FALSE
2021-03-25  3110.87         TRUE         FALSE
```

Here is the working progress code

```
    # the date in a loop
    for date in ['2021-03-19','2021-03-25']:

        date_str=''

        date_str=date_str.join(date) # convert date from list into string

        on_season=pd.to_datetime(date_str)

        on_season = on_season.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        #try to make the day range

        off_season=pd.to_datetime(date_str) - timedelta(2) 

        off_season=off_season.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # convert datetime object to string

        # I am stuck in the dataframe part
```

Comment: It's not very clear what this means. *desired output since the date in the loop here are '2021-03-19','2021-03-25'. So on_season is between '2021-03-19' and '2021-03-17' and '2021-03-25' and '2021-03-23'.* Maybe reiterate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to calculate the `ds` diff between adjacent rows:

```
df.ds = pd.to_datetime(df.ds)
# check if difference between two rows are smaller than 2
df['on_season'] = df.ds.diff().dt.days.fillna(0) < 2
df['off_season'] = ~df['on_season']

df
          ds        y  on_season  off_season
0 2021-03-17  3135.73       True       False
1 2021-03-18  3027.99       True       False
2 2021-03-19  3074.96       True       False
3 2021-03-22  3110.87      False        True
4 2021-03-23  3110.87       True       False
5 2021-03-24  3110.87       True       False
6 2021-03-25  3110.87       True       False
```

Comment: I am new to Pandas, it seems `df.ds.diff()` gives the difference in days, any reason why you added `.dt.days` to specifically parse the result to float?

Comment: @KarthikS I converted it from timedelta to numeric so we can compare it with 2.

Comment: Gosh this is really a smart way of solving this. Let me try to see if it will work on multiple longer-dated "date" in the loop like ['2020-10-01', '2021-03-19','2021-03-25']: